# How does MPI_Reduce with MPI_MIN work?

Tags: c, mpi

if I have this code:

```
int main(void) {
    int result=0;
    int num[6] = {1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 1};
    if (my_rank != 0) {
        MPI_Reduce(num, &result, 6, MPI_INT, MPI_MIN, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    } else {
        MPI_Reduce(num, &result, 6, MPI_INT, MPI_MIN, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD)
        printf("result = %d\n", result);
    }
}
```

the result print is 1 ;

But if the `num[0]=9`; then the result is `9`

I read to solve this problem I must to define the variable `num` as array. 
I can't understand how the function `MPI_Reduce` works with `MPI_MIN`. Why, if the `num[0]` is not equal to the smallest number, then I must to define the variable `num` as array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MPI_Reduce` performs a reduction over the members of the communicator - not the members of the local array. `sendbuf` and `recvbuf` must both be of the same `size`.

I think [the standard](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf) says it best:

> Thus, all processes provide **input buffers and output buffers of the same length**, with elements of the same type. Each process can provide one element, or **a sequence of elements, in which case the combine operation is executed element-wise on each entry of the sequence**.

MPI does not get the minimum of all elements in the array, you have to do that manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MPI_MIN to obtain the min value among those passed via reduction. 
Lets' examine the function declaration:

```
int MPI_Reduce(void* sendbuf, void* recvbuf, int count, MPI_Datatype
                datatype, MPI_Op op, int root, MPI_Comm comm)
```

Each process send it's value (or array of values) using the buffer `sendbuff`.
The process identified by the `root` id receive the buffers and stores them in the buffer `recvbuf`. The number of elements to receive from each of the other processes is specified in count, so that `recvbuff` must be allocated with dimension `sizeof(datatype)*count`. 
If each process has only one integer to send (count = 1) then `recvbuff` it's also an integer, If each process has two integers then `recvbuff` it's an array of integers of size 2. See this nice [post](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-reduce-and-allreduce/) for further explanations and nice pictures.

Now it should be clear that your code is wrong, `sendbuff` and `recvbuff` must be of the same size and there is no need of the condition: `if(myrank==0)`. Simply, `recvbuff` has meaning only for the `root` process and `sendbuff` for the others.
In your example you can assign one or more element of the array to a different process and then compute the minvalue (if there are as many processes as values in the array) or the array of minvalues (if there are more values than processes).

Here is a working example that illustrates the usage of MPI_MIN, MPI_MAX and MPI_SUM (slightly modified from [this](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/pingali/CS378/2008sp/lectures/mpiExamples.txt)), in the case of simple values (not array).
Each process do some work, depending on their rank and send to the root process the time spent doing the work. The root process collect the times and output the min, max and average values of the times.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int myrank, numprocs;

/* just a function to waste some time */
float work()
{
    float x, y;
    if (myrank%2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i) {
            x = i/0.001;
            y += x;
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
            x = i/0.001;
            y += x;
        }
    }    
    return y;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int node;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &node);

    printf("Hello World from Node %d\n",node);

   /*variables used for gathering timing statistics*/
    double mytime,   
           maxtime,
           mintime,
           avgtime;

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);  /*synchronize all processes*/

    mytime = MPI_Wtime();  /*get time just before work section */
    work();
    mytime = MPI_Wtime() - mytime;  /*get time just after work section*/

    /*compute max, min, and average timing statistics*/
    MPI_Reduce(&mytime, &maxtime, 1, MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_MAX, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Reduce(&mytime, &mintime, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MIN, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Reduce(&mytime, &avgtime, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    /* plot the output */
    if (myrank == 0) {
        avgtime /= numprocs;
        printf("Min: %lf  Max: %lf  Avg:  %lf\n", mintime, maxtime,avgtime);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

If I run this on my OSX laptop, this is what I get:

```
urcaurca$ mpirun -n 4 ./a.out
Hello World from Node 3
Hello World from Node 0
Hello World from Node 2
Hello World from Node 1
Min: 0.000974  Max: 0.985291  Avg:  0.493081
```