# How to calculate percentage ratio?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I am new to `mpi` and I am trying to write a mini `C` program that calculates the percentage *ratio* of numbers that the user inputs.

The percentage ratio is calculated by that expression

```
`δi = ((xi – xmin ) / (xmax – xmin )) * 100`.
```

The numbers that the user inputs are stored in an array of fixed size `data[100]` and are scattered to all processes (this program is supposed to work only with four processes).
The problem I am facing is that the division doesn't work although all the processes have the data. For example if the user inputs the numbers `{1, 2, 3, 4}` the expected percentage ratio according to the mathematical expression is `{0, 33.3, 66.6, 100}` but instead I am getting `{0,0,100,100}`. This is what I have.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"


int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int my_rank;
    int total_processes;
    int root = 0;
    int data[100];
    int loc_data[100];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &total_processes);

    int input_size = 0;
    if (my_rank == 0){
        printf("Input how many numbers: ");
        scanf("%d", &input_size);
        
        printf("Input the elements of the array: ");
        for(int i=0; i<input_size; i++){
            scanf("%d", &data[i]);
        }
    }

    MPI_Bcast(&input_size, 1, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int loc_num = input_size/total_processes;

    MPI_Scatter(&data, loc_num, MPI_INT, loc_data, loc_num, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int global_max = 0;
    int global_min = 0;
    MPI_Reduce(&loc_data, &global_max, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_MAX, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Reduce(&loc_data, &global_min, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_MIN, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    

    float loc_delta[100];
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    float p = 0;

     for(int j = 0; j< loc_num; j++){
        x = loc_data[j] - global_min;
        y = global_max - global_min;
    }

    MPI_Bcast(&y, 1, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
    
    for(int j = 0; j< loc_num ; j++){
        p = (x / y) * 100;
        printf("p= %f \n", p);
        loc_delta[j] = p; 
    }

    float final_delta[100];
    MPI_Gather(&loc_delta, 1, MPI_FLOAT, final_delta, 1, MPI_FLOAT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


    if(my_rank == 0){
        printf("max number: %d\n", global_max);
        printf("min number: %d\n", global_min);
        
        for(int i = 0; i<input_size; i++)
            printf("delta[%d]: %.2f | ", i+1, final_delta[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

        MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

First:

```
int global_max = 0;
int global_min = 0;
MPI_Reduce(&loc_data, &global_max, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_MAX, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Reduce(&loc_data, &global_min, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_MIN, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

unfortunately,

> MPI does not get the minimum of all elements in the array, you have to
> do that manually. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37930116/how-does-mpi-reduce-with-mpi-min-work))

Therefore, one needs to first calculate the `min` and the `max` within each process' array, and then one can reduce those `min` and `max` results among the other processes. Since, all processes should have the `min` and `max` of that array, instead of [MPI_Reduce](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.3/www3/MPI_Reduce.html), you should use [MPI_Allreduce](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.3/www3/MPI_Allreduce.html). And your code would look like the following:

```
int local_max = loc_data[0];
int local_min = loc_data[0];
for(int i = 1; i < loc_num; i++){
   local_max = (local_max > loc_data[i]) ?  local_max : loc_data[i];
   local_min = (local_min < loc_data[i]) ?  local_min : loc_data[i];  
}

int global_max = local_max;
int global_min = local_min;

MPI_Allreduce(&local_max, &global_max, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_MAX, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Allreduce(&local_min, &global_min, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_MIN, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Unless you are assuming that `loc_num=1`, which you should not, this code

```
  for(int j = 0; j< loc_num; j++){
        x = loc_data[j] - global_min;
        y = global_max - global_min;
    }
```

overrides the same `x` and `y`. Moreover, you should not call `MPI_Bcast(&y, 1, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`, you want for all the processes to first calculate in parallel their work based on the formula:

```
δi = ((xi – xmin ) / (xmax – xmin )) * 100.
```

and only then send their work back to the *master* process. So each process should apply that formula to their input indices, stored the results in an array and send it back to the *master* process. Like so:

```
float loc_delta[100];
float y = global_max - global_min;
for(int j = 0; j< loc_num; j++){
    loc_delta[j] = (((float) (loc_data[j] - global_min) / y) * 100.0); 
}
 
float final_delta[100];
MPI_Gather(&loc_delta, loc_num, MPI_FLOAT, final_delta, loc_num, MPI_FLOAT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Notice that I am casting `(((float) (loc_data[j] - global_min) / y) * 100.0);`  to *float*. Otherwise, `C` would return an `int` representation of the result.